# How to use table pointer with fonction in C

Tags: c

I have a struct like:

```
struct oda {
    char isim[10];         
    int id[1];                       
};
```

and 2d table created with this type:

```
struct oda* tab[X][Y];
```

This table should be allocated dynamically on memory, so if we have product placement on x and y tab[X][Y] should point to our struct, otherway value of pointer tab[X][Y] = NULL

I have created a fonction for init this table:

```
void init_tab_empty(struct oda** ptr_tab)
{
    int i, j;   
    
    for (i = 0; i < X; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < Y; j++) {
            ptr_tablo[i][j] = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not working, i have:

```
Cannot assign a value of type void * to an entity of type struct oda
```

Can you help me please?

I played with *'s but i can't understand what can i do more
it seems correct for me but not working

Comment: `struct oda* tab[X][Y];` means a 2-d array of pointers to structs, not a pointer to a 2-d array of structs.

Comment: Yes, this is 2-d array of pointers to structs, each 2-d array of pointers should be NULL when i execute init_tab_empty. And i will create pointer value for each product placed on this table who point to our struct oda with another fontion called init_product. Example: tab[3][4] is empty tab[3][4] = NULL, id tab[3][4] have a product, tab[3][4] = (struct oda*)malloc(X * Y * sizeof(tab[X][Y]));

Comment: `int** ptr_tab` is not the same as `int ptr_tab[X][Y]`. The double pointer doesn't have information about the row width.

Comment: you can't pass a 2-d array to a `TYPE **` parameter. I know there are past questions about this, but I don't have a link.

Comment: i am calling fonction like this: init_tab_empty(&tab);   , what i need to do if my method is false?

Comment: Why does the function say `int **` instead of `struct oda**`?

Comment: i have already using: void init_tab_empty(struct oda** ptr_tab) but i have same result, corrected on thread

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, you want to pass a table to your function. Then the following change will make it okay:

```
void init_tab_empty(struct oda ***tab)
{
    int i, j;   
    
    for (i = 0; i < DIM_X; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < DIM_Y; j++) {
            tab[i][j] = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

This tells the function that you will input a table of pointers to `struct oda` data type.

There, you have:

```
struct oda *my_tab[DIM_X][DIM_Y];
...
init_tab_empty(my_tab);
```

Comment: You can't use an initializer list when declaring a variable-length array.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed, nice catch! Changed

Comment: @Jib thank you for your answer, tried it but i have "read access violation" for tab[i][j] = NULL;

Comment: @MusaTombul Did you declare the table as `const`?